# I cant speciy the file.path in R

Tags: r, file

Everytime I give the command in file.path, it always gives this error message , no matter what.

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
cannot open file 'C/Users/Jbhanda/Desktop/NEW_GSE52778_All_Sample_FPKM_Matrix.csv': No such file or directory

I need to link my .csv file in desktop to the file.path command in R

Answer (score 0):

First I note you are missing a colon after `C`, which (assuming this is a Windows machine) should be `C:/`.

Secondly you can try escaped backslashes:

`C:\\Users\\Jbhanda\\Desktop\\NEW_GSE52778_All_Sample_FPKM_Matrix.csv`